# Integrating Clearaudit into MSBuild/Devenv.com

Tags: msbuild, clearcase

I have a rather complex solution where dependencies between projects are "good enough" for single-processor builds, but most likely neither complete nor minimal. Now I'd like to make a build with Clearaudit, which tracks the inputs used to generate a certain output file; running `devenv.com ... /Build` under Clearaudit gives some results, but includes too many input files in the result set.

I'd now like to go the other way 'round: teach MSBuild to invoke "clearaudit /c *original-command*" for each command, and ideally clearmake instead of make for the Makefile based projects.

Is there a mechanism that lets me modify the command line right before execution?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in [`clermake` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearmake.htm) or in [about clearaudit](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146385) indicates that you can achieve what you want.

That leaves you with some "trick" to try like a special path with a `make.exe` which actually call `clearmake`, because that "`make.exe`" would be a custom script instead of the normal command, and would be found first in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: It's more an MSBuild problem, from what I can see -- MSBuild calls most of the compile steps directly, but some of the (legacy and/or cross-platform) projects in the solution are Makefile-based. Basically I want to get at proper file-level dependencies across the entire solution, which I will then transmogrify into inter-project dependencies by the magic of perl.

Comment: @SimonRichter So it looks like you need to define/call a custom make (as in this project: http://tangram-plugin-framework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Demo/AdvancedDemo/PlatForm.groupproj)

Comment: That, and a custom MSBuild -- which is somewhat more effort.